# HttpsURLConnection is not working with IPv6Address. Equivalent CURL command only work with '-g' option

Tags: java, rest, curl, https

I am trying to access an HTTPS rest service using HttpsURLConnection.

It's working fine with IPv4 but not working with IPv6 address.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    disableSSL();
    URL url = new URL("https://[IPv6Address]:400/managemnt/mgmt-1.0/profile");
    final HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpsConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
.......
}
```

disableSSL is standard code to skip SSL validation as below :

```
 private static void disableSSL() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        } };

        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

        // Create all-trusting host name verifier
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        };

        // Install the all-trusting host verifier
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
    }
```

Full stack of Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:933)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at com.saurav.util.Example.main(Example.java:49)
```

When we try to access the REST using curl below command was failing :

curl -k -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://[IPv6Address]:400/managemnt/mgmt-1.0/profile

But when I added '-g' option to "Disable URL sequences and ranges using {} and []" it worked.

Is there any such option available for HttpsURLConnection ? How I can solve this?

Thanks for your time to read such a long post !

Comment: “not working with IPv6 address” How can you tell?  If there’s an exception, edit your question and include the *entire stack trace* of the exception in your question.  (It’s unlikely that the IPv6 \[…\] address notation is the cause of your problem.)

Comment: @VGR: I have added the stack trace. I know this is highly unlikely that IPv6  will not work because of [] but that's the only thing I am able to find in my code. From curl, I am able to access URL so I can confirm that IPv6 URL is working.

Comment: The exception suggests that the IPv6 address was correctly parsed, but the address could not be reached.  I would guess that either your machine’s IPv6 is not active, or IPv6 is not supported by your network and/or provider.